# Using 'grep' to search for a specific pattern

Tags: linux, grep, input, output, patterns

I'm playing with the Linux terminal and I have to do a exercise which states that I have to find inside a file for any line that contains at least an a, b and c, it doesn't matter it the lane has 2 a, 1 b and 1c or 1 a, 55 b, and 3 c. Like I said it needs to have at lest one a, one b and one c.

Example:

Input:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccc
abcabcabcabc
hhahhhbhhhhc
aabbccpppppp
thisisrandom
nononononono
aandbandcnoo
dddddddddddd
```

Output(valid):

```
abcabcabcabc
hhahhhbhhhhc
aabbccpppppp
aandbandcnoo
```

All the content are inside a .txt file.

Edit: It needs to be done with a regular expression and metacharacters

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn regexes, `[abc]` means at least one a, one b, one c.

`grep [abc] FILE.txt`

[You can learn regexes with grep here](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html)